# JavaScript Drag and Drop. And unhide the detals after dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have some issues regarding drag and drop in javascript.

I have 2 tables -  Table 1 and Table 2.  I have the details of the each employee present in each cell of table 1. And only Employee image is visible in each cell. and remaining details are hidden.

The each cell of table 1 is draggable and can be dropped to table 2.

When i drag particular cell from Table 1 and drop it to Table 2, The hidden details of the specific employee should be shown in table 2.

including the image, the hidden details of the specific cell should be shown in table2 after dropped in table 2.

It is possible for me to drag contents from one table to another table.. And could not show the hidden details in the another table.

Comment: could you post a fiddle please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/6/

Here i got one example frrom fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking at?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/156/

Main change from you fiddle:

```
           target.children('h2').show();
```

Comment: @Arun BS: Can you accept my answer if you are ok with the solution?

Comment: Oh man thank you very much.. :-) i was looking exactly the saaame... 
Thanks again.. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/mX7FY/1/)

**HTML**

```
     Table1
<table border="1" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
         <td class="hiddenTD">Demo Name</td>
        <td class="hiddenTD">Demo Description</td>
        <td>Picture</td>
    </thead>
    <tr class="drag">
        <td class="hiddenTD">Demo1</td>
        <td class="hiddenTD">DemoDescription</td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Demo Picture"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="drag">
        <td class="hiddenTD">Demo2</td>
        <td class="hiddenTD">DemoDescription</td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Demo2 Picture"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="drag">
        <td class="hiddenTD">Demo3</td>
        <td class="hiddenTD">DemoDescription</td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Demo3 Picture"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
Table2
<table id="droppable" border="1" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
         <td>Demo Name</td>
        <td >Demo Description</td>
        <td>Picture</td>
    </thead>

</table>
```

**CSS**

```
    .hiddenTD
{
    display:none;
}

thead td{
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".drag" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $tr=$('<tr/>');
        $tr.html(ui.draggable.html());
        $tr.find('td').removeClass('hiddenTD');
        $(this).append($tr);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response Sethuraman..

Comment: This is also what i am looking for my further step.. Thanks again...